# asp.net web.config impersonation vs application pool identity

Tags: asp.net, identity

If I impersonate a user in the web.config but the application runs under an application pool which uses another identity, which identity would be used when you access resources (say files) on the server?

Another question, can you run a page under a separate identity from rest of the application?

Comment: Are we talking about IIS5, 6 or 7?

Answer (score 12):

When you access resources on the server the user will be the one specified on the impersonation configuration NOT the one on the application pool

**Impersonation enabled for a specific identity. In this instance, ASP.NET impersonates the token generated using an identity specified in the Web.config file.**

```
<identity impersonate="true"
      userName="domain\user" 
      password="password" />
```

**Impersonation enabled. In this instance, ASP.NET impersonates the token passed to it by IIS, which is either an authenticated user or the anonymous Internet user account.**

```
 <identity impersonate="true" />
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

In case you're interested, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649264.aspx) you have an article with a Identity matrix for different impersonate scenarios.

And yes, you can impersonate programatically as Alex Dn said

Comment: So if every app running under an application pool is impersonating a specific user, then app pool identity is meaningless?

Comment: @user1110437: yes, for accessing "external" resources the app pool user is not relevant (when impersonate = true).

Comment: when you say external, you mean outside the app or the server?

Answer (score 0):

1) In web.config.

2) You can do impersonation in code behind:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

or [Another article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/Feb/24/Using-programmatic-Impersonation-from-an-ASPNET-Page)

Comment: So if I impersonate in the web.config, then application pool identity is meaningless?

Comment: Not exactly, actually web.config overrides the Application Pool identity. One application pool may be used for more than one sites. With web.config you can specify identity per site. So using the AppPool identity will work to, but usually it's recommended to use web.config.