# asp.net create folder and file in other server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, io

In my asp.net application I have an option to take photographs, these photographs should not store the hosting server, the photographs should be stored on another server. (\192.168.1.103\ca\photos\
I use this code

```
public void EstructuraReclamo(string Producto, string Poliza, string Sucursal,string Reclamo, string Item) {
string Mensaje = string.Empty;
string DirServidor = DireccionIP(ref Mensaje, "SCANDATOS", Sucursal, "RECLAMOS");           
try
{
    string DirReclamo =DirServidor + Producto + @"\" + Poliza + @"\Item" + Item + @"\" + Reclamo;
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(DirReclamo)){
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(DirReclamo);
    }
    System.Data.DataTable dtSubdirectorios = ListaSubDirectorio(ref Mensaje, "SCANRECLAMO");
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dtSubdirectorios.Rows) { 
        string SubDir = DirReclamo + @"\" + dr["apa_glosa"].ToString();
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(SubDir))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SubDir);
    }

}
catch (Exception ex){
    Mensaje = ex.Message.ToString();
}
```

But the folders are not created?
When I execute the program from VS2010 the folders are created, but when publish the site the folders are no created
How I can solve this problem?

The version IIS is 6.0

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The user account that you are running VS as has different permissions than the user account your code runs in when published.

Comment: Are you getting an exception by chance? If so, what is that exception?

Comment: Hi Michael, no I'm not getting an exception

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't know whether or not you're getting an exception at the moment, this is almost assuredly a permissions issue. IIS is going to send the credentials the Application Pool is running under when trying to create the folders. This is **generally** defaulted to `NETWORK SERVICE`.

Have a look at the user the Application Pool is running under, then check out the permissions of the root folder, and ensure that user has `Write` access.

Once the Application Pool user has permissions -you're good.

Comment: Hi Michael Perronoud, Yes, I have to set permissions, so far can not find a way to give permission to access the shared directory, I must also take into account security .. if you had any more information or tutorial to guide me I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a permissions issue, when you run the program using visual studio the application runs with your own credentials, however when the site is run in IIS it will run with whichever account is assigned to the application pool and by default this will be a local account on the machine which won't have any permissions on a remote server.

If you [use impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745335/asp-net-web-config-impersonation-vs-application-pool-identity) you can setup an account which has the relevant permissions on the remote server and your application will have access to those remote folders/files.

Comment: Hi Richard Wilson, In my application I am using forms authentication, I don't have configured Active Directory. What I need is that user take a picture and this is stored on a remote server, as I can do with impersonation? Find out this issue but so far I can't do this,  I need to do the impersonation that only apply to the shared directory not the entire project .. if you have more info to share I would appreciate